# Getting value error for converting string to float while trying to read from annotation file

Tags: python

While trying to train a model for my own dataset, I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '281.46762 316.82224 306.0123 270.65768 136.2258 160.62991 176.29044 151.88632 तब'
File "/Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/icdar.py", line 609, in generator    
text_polys, text_tags = load_annoataion(txt_fn)
```

How to correctly convert string to float?
Here's the code for loading annotations in txt format:

```
def load_annoataion(p):
    text_polys = []
    text_tags = []
    if not os.path.exists(p):
        return np.array(text_polys, dtype=np.float32)
    with open(p, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for line in reader:
            label = line[-1]
            line = [i.strip('\ufeff').strip('\xef\xbb\xbf') for i in line]
            x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 = list(map(float, line[:8]))
            text_polys.append([[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4]])
            if label == '*' or label == '###':
                text_tags.append(True)
            else:
                text_tags.append(False)
        return np.array(text_polys, dtype=np.float32), np.array(text_tags, dtype=np.bool)
```

Comment: You can't convert that string to a float because there's a non-digit character at the end.

Comment: @C.Lewis Can u tell me how do i use that annotation file then? I want to train my model using that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clean up your data but based on that line in the error, here is something to help you out

```py
def floats_from_string(line):
    nums = []
    try:
        for num in line.split(" "):
            nums.append(float(num))  # <-- cast your string to a float
    except ValueError:  # <- catch the possible non floats
        pass  # <-- don't really need them so do nothing
    return nums # <- return  list of float
```

Comment: Can u tell me how to use this? I can't implement it

Comment: Sure, in the section `for line in reader`, pass in the line you declared into this function and you should get back a list of floats. Easy!

Comment: It led to me another error `Attribute error: list has no attribute split`. Actually i have to traverse through 10 lines like `281.46762 316.82224 306.0123 270.65768 136.2258 160.62991 176.29044 151.88632 तब`. can you modify my code to tell me how to get list of floats for multiple lines like that. I think I'm still implementing your solution wrong.